# How to insert the value into database field?

Tags: python, sql, web2py

I have a database `test` with table `text2` and a function `morpho` that creates values from one field of this table.

```
test.define_table('text2',
                  Field('title', unique=True),
                  Field('author'),
                  Field('body', 'text'),
                  Field('dictionary'),
                  format='%(title)s')

def morpho():
    text2 = test(test.text2.id==request.args(0)).select().first()
    # (skip details)
    test.text2.insert(dictionary=list_of_sent)
    return dict(list_of_sent=list_of_sent)
```

How I can insert the result of the function in the field `dictionary` of the same row, from which a value was?

Now the result come into the next row...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Row` object, you can use its `.update_record` method to update the associated database record:

```
    text2 = test(test.text2.id==request.args(0)).select().first()
    text2.update_record(dictionary=list_of_sent)
```

Or, you can avoid needing to select the record from the database at all and instead just do the update directly:

```
    test(test.text2.id==request.args(0)).update(dictionary=list_of_sent)
```